# How to install Source Code Pro Font on Arch Linux

Tags: linux, fonts, adobe, zsh, archlinux

I am currently follwoing [this](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs#default-installation) guide to install spacemacs and it has suggested that I use the `adobe font` [`source code pro`](https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-code-pro).

Now the problem is that I have installed Adobe Font Development Kit for OpenType using `yaourt -S adobe-source-code-pro-fonts`, but can't seem to get the command `makeotf -h` to work. I simply get a `zsh: command not found: makeotf`. Not sure why this is the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `makeotf` is only used to *build* the font files from source.

That should not be necessary since you installed them through `yaourt`. So you already have the fonts. Now you need to config Spacemacs to use them.